# Как можно добиться прокрутки колесиком мыши содержимого DBGridEh, а не записи в ней?

Tags: delphi

Я знаю, что при подключении MemTableEh так и происходит.
Но возможно ли обойтись без подключения MemTableEh ?
Мне подсказали, что если использовать `DBGridEhCenter.TryUseViewScroll := False;`, то это должно повлиять на все DBGridEh, используемые в проекте, но я не понял как это работает. Вставкой данной строки я ничего не добился.

Comment: Разобрался и решил проблему подключив MemTableEh. Вопрос снят. Спасибо всем кто прочел хотя бы вопрос.  ;)